# Qsort removing elements

Tags: c, qsort

I am trying to sort an array of structs with qsort but when I display the sorted structs all but one are missing.

Here are the relevant parts of my code:

```
typedef struct {
    char firstName[20];
    char lastName[20];
    float height;
} myStruct;
```

....

```
 else if (argc > 2) {
            FILE * inf;
            inf = fopen(argv[2], "r");
            errorCheck(fscanf(inf, "%d", &numStructs));
            people = (myStruct*)malloc(sizeof(myStruct) * numStructs);
            for (int i = 0; i < numStructs; ++i) {
                    errorCheck(fscanf(inf, "%s %s %f", firstName, lastName, &height));
                    person = people + (sizeof(myStruct) * i);
                    initMyStruct(person, firstName, lastName, height);
            }
            printf("struct read in");
    }
```

...

```
    if (strcmp(argv[1], "last") == 0) {
            fprintf(stdout, "last name sort if statement, \n");
            //myStruct* person = people + (sizeof(myStruct));
            qsort(people, numStructs, sizeof(myStruct), lastCmp);
    }
    else {
            fprintf(stdout, "height sort if statement, \n");
            //myStruct* person = people + (sizeof(myStruct));
            qsort(people, numStructs, sizeof(myStruct), heightCmp);
    }
```

and my compare functions

```
int lastCmp(const void *a, const void *b) {
        myStruct* c = (myStruct *)a;
        myStruct* d = (myStruct *)b;
        return(strcmp(c->lastName, d->lastName));
}

int heightCmp(const void* a, const void* b) {
        myStruct *personA = (myStruct *)a;
        myStruct *personB = (myStruct *)b;
        return((personA->height > personB->height) - (personB->height > personA->height));
}
```

Here is the output:

```
First name: Abigail, last name: Egan, height: 5.300000, 
First name: Jim, last name: Gardner, height: 5.500000,
First name: Jenna, last name: Adams, height: 5.500000,
First name: Maggie, last name: Johnson, height: 4.900000,
First name: Chelsea, last name: Harrison, height: 5.400000,
First name: Anna, last name: DeHart, height: 5.000000,

First name: , last name: , height: 0.000000,
First name: , last name: , height: 0.000000,
First name: , last name: , height: 0.000000,
First name: , last name: , height: 0.000000,
First name: , last name: , height: 0.000000,
First name: Abigail, last name: Egan, height: 5.300000,
```

(My apologies about the readability, the formatting didn't stay.) Let me know if you need to see other parts of my code. The first output is the array of structs immediately after reading them in. The second is after sorting. I need to keep using qsort, I can't use a different method.

Comment: "*Let me know if you need to see other parts of my code*" - that's not how this works. Post a [mcve].

Comment: `person = people + (sizeof(myStruct) * i);` has undefined behavior.

Comment: Aside: in `errorCheck(fscanf(inf, "%s %s %f", firstName, lastName, &height));` how does `errorCheck` know how many values were supposed to be input (here 3)? That is the essential check of the `scanf` function family, which will also catch `EOF`. In a perfect world, check for `EOF`, but no input can be ***trusted***, so check the number of items converted.

Comment: `people + (sizeof(myStruct) * i);` like melpomene says it's UB. When doing pointer arithmetic you don't have worry about the size of the structures, that's the compiler job. `people + i` will do the job.

Comment: The discrepancy between `qsort(people, numStructs, sizeof(myStruct), lastCmp);` and `qsort((void *)people, numStructs, sizeof(myStruct), heightCmp);` is puzzling.  Probably not harmful, but why the inconsistency.  You don't show the printing code.  It isn't a coherent MCVE ([MCVE]).  Your comparator functions play fast and loose with `const`-ness.  You'll probably get away with, but you shouldn't be trying to.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem cannot be reliably analyzed because you did not post the actual source code for a minimal, complete and verifiable example. You would also need o post the input fed to the program.

I will venture a potential explanation for the observed behavior:

- Your test for `fscanf()` success is incorrect: testing against `EOF` is insufficient, you must check that `fscanf()` converted 3 inputs and returned `3`. Incorrect input will cause `fscanf()` to return a short count and input will be ignored by the subsequent calls, leaving your variables in an inconsistent state.
- Incorrect input is for example `Michael J Fox 5.2`: firstName would get `Michael`, lastName would get `J` and conversion for `height` would fail. Subsequent calls would consume the input stream out of sync...

Comment: I am aware of those potential bugs and I know that that neither are causing this issue. My errorCheck function checks to make sure fscanf() returns the correct number. I am reasonably confident that the bug is in what I am passing to qsort or in my compare functions.

Comment: You do not know what is causing the problem. The output provided may indicate that you are sorting more elements than were read into the array,  which could be explained by a problem in the parsing phase. Subtile problems can hide in plain sight in innocent looking C code, posting a complete example along with the actual input is the best way to get a correct answer on stackoverflow.